# Thread-safe changes to a ConcurrentDictionary

Tags: c#, parallel-processing, task-parallel-library, parallel.foreach, concurrentdictionary

I am populating a `ConcurrentDictionary` in a `Parallel.ForEach` loop:

```
var result = new ConcurrentDictionary<int, ItemCollection>();

Parallel.ForEach(allRoutes, route => 
{
    // Some heavy operations

    lock(result)
    {
        if (!result.ContainsKey(someKey))
        {
            result[someKey] = new ItemCollection();
        }

        result[someKey].Add(newItem);
    }
}
```

How do I perform the last steps in a thread-safe manner without using the lock statement?

**EDIT:**  Assume that `ItemCollection` is thread-safe.

Comment: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd997369.aspx

Comment: Is `ItemCollection.Add` thread-safe? If not, you'll need a lock.

Comment: @ken2k: Except my situation has a conditional element to it.  If the key doesn't exist, create a new `ItemCollection`, otherwise add an item to the existing `ItemCollection` at that key.

Comment: @dcastro: Ah yes, please assume that ItemCollection is thread-safe.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I think you want [`GetOrAdd`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee378677%28v=vs.110%29.aspx), which is explicitly designed to either fetch an existing item, or add a new one if there's no entry for the given key.

```
var collection = result.GetOrAdd(someKey, _ => new ItemCollection());
collection.Add(newItem);
```

As noted in the question comments, this assumes that `ItemCollection` is thread-safe.

Comment: That may not be as safe as it appears: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10486579/concurrentdictionary-pitfall-are-delegates-factories-from-getoradd-and-addorup

Comment: @jeffdot: I don't think that's a problem in this case - the `ItemCollection` constructor doesn't need to be called within any locks... What issue are you envisaging?

Comment: Because there was discussion of locking, and because the `ConcurrentDictionary` does have an internal lock, I felt we were adding risk by leading people to think that `GetOrAdd` and `AddOrUpdate` are atomic or called within the dictionary's lock.  I have since noted that you are giving fair warning that `ItemCollection` must be threadsafe.

Answer (score 1):

You need to use the [`GetOrAdd`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee378676.aspx) method.

```
var result = new ConcurrentDictionary<int, ItemCollection>();

int someKey = ...;
var newItem = ...;

ItemCollection collection = result.GetOrAdd(someKey, _ => new ItemCollection());
collection.Add(newItem);
```

Answer (score 1):

Assuming `ItemCollection.Add` is not thread-safe, you *will* need a lock, but you *can* reduce the size of the critical region.

```
var collection = result.GetOrAdd(someKey, k => new ItemCollection());

lock(collection)
    collection.Add(...);
```

Update: Since it seems to be thread-safe, you don't need the lock at all

```
var collection = result.GetOrAdd(someKey, k => new ItemCollection());
collection.Add(...);
```

Comment: The OP replied to your comment saying that ItemCollection *is* thread-safe.

Comment: @JonSkeet Thanks, hadn't noticed.