# ConcurrentDictionary: How do I add if value does not exist or condition fails?

Tags: c#, concurrency

I am trying to implement extension method for `ConcurrentDictionary` that functionally gets the value from dictionary if key exists. If the key does not exists or the condition (in `predicate`) fails, it tries to get the value by calling `valueFactory`. Below is the method I have written.

```
public static TValue ConditionalGetOrAdd<TKey, TValue>(
    this ConcurrentDictionary<TKey, TValue> dictionary,
    TKey key,
    Func<TValue, bool> predicate,
    Func<TKey, TValue> valueFactory)
{
    TValue value = dictionary.GetOrAdd(key, valueFactory);

    if (!predicate(value))
    {
        value = valueFactory(key);
        dictionary[key] = value;
    }

    return value;
}
```

There are two issues here. I may call `valueFactory` twice in case the `predicate` returns false. This would be redundant operation. In addition, the entire method is not atomic. If one thread is inside the `if` block, the other thread will not wait for it to complete before calling `GetOrAdd` or `predicate`.

Is it possible to get this accomplished without taking lock on entire dictionary? In my case, the `valueFactory` is costly (makes an HTTP request internally), while `predicate` is quite cheap. Let me know if you have a solution. I am okay with modifying the entire method if it serves the purpose.

Comment: Why can't you move the predicate check to the top if, apparently, it is not dependent on whether it is inside the dictionary?

Comment: `predicate` will take the `value` that we get from dictionary. Unless I call `TryGet` or `GetOrAdd` first, I will not be able to know the value. Let me know if I did not understand the comment.

Comment: Ah I see now. Seems like you should just do a normal `TryGet()` instead of a `GetOrAdd()` since you don't want to add it? That way you will only call `valueFactory` at most once when the predicate fails.

Comment: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee378664(v=vs.110).aspx

Comment: Thanks. How do I prevent race condition then. I don't want while thread is calling `valueFactory`, other thread too get inside and to the same. @john, I will see if `AddOrUpdate` works for me. Give me some time.

Comment: I think `dictionary.AddOrUpdate(key, valueFactory, (k, v) => predicate(v) ? v : valueFactory(k))` should work for me.

Answer (score 2):

Thanks, @john for the suggestion. `AddOrUpdate` should work for me. Adding the new method body below:

```
return dictionary.AddOrUpdate(
     key,
     valueFactory,
     (k, v) => predicate(v) ? v : valueFactory(k));
```

I would keep this as an extension method instead of calling `AddOrUpdate` directly in the callers, as it would allow me reuse the `valueFactory` delegate at two places above.

Comment: Note that AddOrUpdate is [not atomic](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/collections/thread-safe/how-to-add-and-remove-items). The value factories may be called more than once for given key.

Comment: Woah! that's surprising. Thanks for the heads up. I checked this answer: https://stackoverflow.com/a/10487983/470119. It seems `AddOrUpdate` method will alternatively call `addValueFactory`/`updateValueFactory` until `TryAdd`/`TryUpdate` respectively succeeds on the factory-returned value. I will ensure that there's no side effect on calling `valueFactory` more than once.

Comment: It is not surprising. It is well documented of all xORy style functions for ConcurrentDictionary<> class that any delegates are invoked outside of any locks held by the class itself.